kvmをcloud-initを使って作成したが、初期のログインパスワードがわからない
やったこと
kvmを使ってvmを作成したいと思っています。
以下のような、cloud-configを作り、実際にvmも立ち上がりログイン画面に行くところまではできています。
#cloud-config
ssh_pwauth: false
locale: en_US.UTF-8
timezone: Asia/Tokyo
hostname: test
users:
  - name: admin
    ssh_import_id: gh:***
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    shell: /bin/bash
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: $6$rounds=4096$gk./9Yzvtnzd9O5P$6cznFMBNFMPz1M0TswloPqCyVIn/Jp3nlT7rVlyreQq8pH1JHFd68Q7wGZ4Tpnit2ZHx48eZ0d3QGHtWvWMva0
    uid: 1000
runcmd:
  # add sshpubkey from gh
  - [ sh, -c, ssh-import-id -o /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys gh:***; chown -R admin:admin /home/admin/.ssh/ ]



困っていること
ログイン画面で
ID : admin
password : password
と入力しても、Login incorrectといわれています。

お手上げ状態です。
無知すぎてわからないです。
どうすればいいのでしょうか？

この回答は、結論として"password"でログインできるはずとなっているため、参考程度でお願いします。

passwdに設定しているハッシュ化された文字列を生成するために入力した文字列がパスワードです。
passwdに設定している文字列はどこから入手しましたか？もし、何かのサンプルのコピペであった場合、その方法自体が間違っています。passwdに設定する文字列は自分で生成すべきです。
Cloud config examples - cloud-init 24.1.3 documentationには次のように書かれています。

#   passwd: The hash -- not the password itself -- of the password you want
#           to use for this user. You can generate a hash via:
#               mkpasswd --method=SHA-512 --rounds=4096
#           (the above command would create from stdin an SHA-512 password hash
#           with 4096 salt rounds)
#
#           Please note: while the use of a hashed password is better than
#               plain text, the use of this feature is not ideal. Also,
#               using a high number of salting rounds will help, but it should
#               not be relied upon.
#
#               To highlight this risk, running John the Ripper against the
#               example hash above, with a readily available wordlist, revealed
#               the true password in 12 seconds on a i7-2620QM.
#
#               In other words, this feature is a potential security risk and is
#               provided for your convenience only. If you do not fully trust the
#               medium over which your cloud-config will be transmitted, then you
#               should not use this feature. ```


私訳

#   passwd: このユーザーに設定したいパスワードのハッシュ ― パスワードそのもので
#           はない ― である。次のようにしてパスワードを生成できる。
#               mkpasswd --method=SHA-512 --rounds=4096
#           (上記コマンドは、標準入力からソルトラウンド数4096のSHA-512ハッシュパ
#           スワードを生成する)
#
#           備考: 平文よりもハッシュ化されたパスワードを使用したよいが、この機能
#               の使用は理想的ではない。また、ソルトラウンド数を高くすることは有
#               効ではあるが、それに頼るべきではない。
#
#               このリスクを強調するとすれば、上記例にあるハッシュに対して、Jhon
#               the Ripper(訳注: 有名なパスワードクラッキングツール)を利用可能な
#               ワードリスト付きで使用した場合、i7-2620QMでは12秒で真のパスワー
#               ドが発覚した。(訳注: ワードリストでクラックできることから、サン
#               プルのパスワード自体が良いパスワードとは言えない可能性がある。)
#
#               言い換えると、この機能は潜在的なセキュリティーリスクがあり、利便
#               性のためだけに提供されている。cloud-configが送信される媒体を完全
#               に信頼することができない場合、この機能を使うべきではない。 ```


このようにmkpasswdを使って生成した文字列をpasswdに設定します。その時のパスワードはmkpasswdで入力したパスワードになります。plain_text_passwdであればパスワードをそのものを書くこともできますが、セキュリティーリスクは非常に低くなります。ただ、passwd自体もセキュリティーが高いとは言えないため、信頼できない環境に送信する場合は、使うべきではないとされています。(そういう意味では、質問文のに書かれてしまった"$6$rounds=4096$gk./9Yzvtnzd9O5P$6cznFMBNFMPz1M0TswloPqCyVIn/Jp3nlT7rVlyreQq8pH1JHFd68Q7wGZ4Tpnit2ZHx48eZ0d3QGHtWvWMva0"はインターネットに公開されてしまっているため、このパスワード自体を破棄すべきでしょう。)

と、ここまで書いたのですが、"$6$rounds=4096$gk./9Yzvtnzd9O5P$6cznFMBNFMPz1M0TswloPqCyVIn/Jp3nlT7rVlyreQq8pH1JHFd68Q7wGZ4Tpnit2ZHx48eZ0d3QGHtWvWMva0"をJhon the Ripperにかけると"password"でした。ということは、パスワードは"password"であっているはずです。それでうまくいかないとなると、別の原因かも知れません。ここまで調べたので、この回答は参考程度で残しておきます。

ありがとうございます。
他のマシンを数台作ってみたのですがダメでした。
ssh_import_id: gh:***を消したらうまくpasswordで通ったので、謎でした。。。。
いろいろ調べていただきありがとうございます。

Googleによるとkvmで作成したvmの初期ID/Passwordは、

未構成のログインは admin です。 パスワードは admin です。

だそうです

ありがとうございます。
試してみたのですが、ダメでした。。

では、この記事 は参考になるでしょうか？

ありがとうございます。
